# Cruzamento de uma chave primaria com 2 chaves estrangeiras da mesma tabela?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, join

estava estudando um pouco de SQL e me deparei com o seguinte problema:

Possuo 2 tabelas uma chamada Order e outra Locations, segue os campos abaixo:

**ORDER**

id | data_criacao | id_origem | id_destino | operadora |

**LOCATIONS**

id | nome_cidade | nome_estado

Preciso de um join cruzando o campo ID(da tabela Location) com os campos id_origem e id_destinos (da tabela order)

no final precisaria algo do gênero abaixo:

**ID order | operadora | nome do estado**

Como posso fazer esse cruzamento?

Tentativas realizadas por mim:

```
inner join location on location.id = order.id_origem and location.id = id_destino
```

Answer (score 1):

A tabela `LOCATIONS` participará duas vezes da junção uma vez no papel de origem e outra vez no papel de destino.

```
SELECT * FROM ORDER INNER JOIN LOCATIONS origem ON (ORDER.id_origem = origem.id)
                    INNER JOIN LOCATIONS destino ON (ORDER.id_destino = destino.id)
```

substitua o * pela lista de campos desejados (não entendi o seu exemplo `ID order | operadora | nome do estado`, a que se refere este `nome do estado`? Origem ou destino?).

Comment: nesse caso sendo 2 inner join, não vai retornar só os registros que existirem ao mesmo nas duas tabelas?

Comment: Sim, tanto `id_origem` quanto `id_destino` precisarão existir na tabela `LOCATIONS`. Caso ambas, ou uma delas, possam não existir é só substituir o `INNER JOIN` por `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Mas o autor da pergunta não esclareceu este ponto.

Comment: @anonimo, o nome do estado seria, Paraná, São Paulo etc. Dessa forma que você mostrou no select final, eu terei que puxar origem e destino, porém assim, na tabela LOCATION, Eu tenho o ID da cidade, nome da cidade e o estado a qual ela pertence, e na tabela de order eu tenho somente o ID_origem e id_destino, eu quero ver se é possível de no select final me trazer somente o estado das cidades de origem e destino, por isso preciso de um join(se for possível) que use uma chave primária com duas estrangeiras, para no select final eu ter só uma coluna trazendo os estados.

Comment: @anonimo, esse cruzamento que vc fez, eu já realizei também, porém com ele eu trago no select final o estado da minha cidade destino e o estado da minha cidade origem, eu queria não precisar trazer essas duas colunas, queria trazer os estados de origem e destinos em uma coluna somente.

Comment: Poste um exemplo de saída desejado para entendermos o que deseja.

Comment: Tabela LOCATIONS: id | nome_cidade | nome_estado, tabela ORDER id | data_criacao | id_origem | id_destino | operadora |. 

Saída:    Order ID | Operadora | Estado

Comment: Exemplo com dados por favor (e não apenas os nomes dos campos). O que significa `Estado` em sua saída?

Comment: Saída:


Order ID | Operaora | Estado seguindo a ordem desses campos a saída veria


    `001`       `Cometa`       `PR`
    `002`       `Garcia`         `SC`
    `003`       `Clickbus`      `SP`

Comment: Sua tabela `ORDER` tem os campos `id_origem` e `id_destino` que, presumo, referenciem o campo `id` da tabela `LOCATIONS`.
Eu já perguntei, mas parece que você não entendeu, o conteúdo de `Estado` se refere à linha da tabela `LOCATIONS` apontada por `id_origem` ou `id_destino`? Continua acreditando que a query que postei contém estes, e vários outros campos de suas tabelas, apenas coloque na lista de seleção os campos que te interessem. Encerrando esta discussão por aqui pois este tipo de discussão não é o objetivo desta lista, mas pode ser feito no chat.